# Define a three element list of intervals?

Tags: scheme

define a procedure triscet that takes a two-element list of numbers representing an [a, b] interval on the number line, where a < b. Return a three element list of intervals, which results from dividing the given interval into three equal lengths. i.e.

```
(trisect '(-4 8))
((-4 0) (0 4) (4 8))
```

help on writing the procedure?

```
(define triscet
  (lambda '(a b)
   (if < a b)
    (cons (quotient a 3(cons (quotient b 3 ls))))))
```

Am i going in the right direction? or is my logic completely wrong?

Comment: What have you done so far? please don't dump here a homework question without first 1) tagging it as homework and 2) showing what have you tried to solve the problem

Comment: please dont be rude. im here to get help and not to be antagonized. yes it is homework. i dont come here all the time so i didnt know it was imperative to tag a question as homework

Comment: Sorry if that sounded rude, that was not my intention. Add the code you've done so far to the question itself, not as a comment, so other people can take a look at it and help you improve it.

Comment: @ÓscarLópez Homework tag is now blacklisted, we are in the process of removing it. Please don't add or suggest it to be added. See tag for more info.

Comment: @Tim I had no idea, since when it got blacklisted? does it mean that SO won't be helping people with their homework anymore?

Comment: @ÓscarLópez I think it was sometime this week. Policy on 'homework questions' hasn't really changed, though it was felt that the tag for homework was counterproductive. There's a link in the tab description you can follow with more info and discussion.

Answer (score 1):

Your solution so far is not going on the right track. First, from the input provided you should receive a single parameter with a *list* of two elements, not two parameters. And you don't need to check if one is less than the other (unless you expect to receive incorrect inputs, and only as error checking).

Let's think about what needs to be done to split the interval in three parts. Here's the general structure of the solution to get you started (assuming correct inputs), fill-in the blanks yourself:

```
(define (trisect interval)
  (let* ((start  <???>)  ; start of interval
         (end    <???>)  ; end of interval
         (offset <???>)) ; size of each chunk if we divide the interval in 3
    (list (list start <???>)  ; 1st subinterval: [start, start+offset]
          (list <???> <???>)  ; 2nd subinterval: [start+offset, start+2*offset]
          (list <???> end)))) ; 3rd subinterval: [start+2*offset, end]
```